# modeling PROCs for SAS on Hadoop

Tags: sas

This publication:

[Pdf](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hadoopov/68100/PDF/default/hadoopov.pdf)

mentions that SAS can only run (MapReduce?) some modeling PROCs on Hadoop. Does anyone know these PROCs or even better is there an exhaustive list? Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen a list of procedures that will run against Hadoop, it also changes quickly due to additions to SAS Software along with changes in Hadoop.

There is a SAS Support for Hadoop page at [SAS 9.4 Support for Hadoop | RESOURCES / THIRD-PARTY SOFTWARE REFERENCE](https://support.sas.com/resources/thirdpartysupport/v94/hadoop/)

There are a lot of articles off this page but the link for the Hadoop Support Matrix is helpful see what SAS Products support Hadoop including the distribution, version, and any known issues.

There are several papers available but I think this one about [Data Modeling Considerations in Hadoop and Hive by Clark Bradley, Ralph Hollinshead, Scott Kraus, Jason Lefler, Roshan Taheri October 2013](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/data-modeling-hadoop.pdf) might be a good fit for you.

SAS has a variety of products that interact with many database type systems including Hadoop, and the options are growing along with Hadoop. There are some newer products such as SAS Data Loader for Hadoop (and others) that support running jobs using the Spark Engine instead of MapReduce. Also just to clarify most Hadoop clusters run yarn/mapreduce2, not just Mapreduce 1. SAS can support Mapreduce, but most of the time clusters are running yarn/mapreduce2 which SAS also supports. In addition some SAS programs running against Hadoop may not require a Mapreduce job at all sometimes, depending on what you are trying to do.

There are only a few common engines in Hadoop to use honestly. You have the older Mapreduce (1) which is much older. Then came yarn/mapreduce2 after that which is likely the most common execution engine to date. The Spark Engine has been available for a few years but it still pretty new, it is supposed to be faster yet not as flexible as Mapreduce2 from what I've heard. I think Hortonworks has an engine called Apache Tez which will work with SAS from my experience. Apache Tez still uses yarn just instead of Mapreduce2 engine it uses Apache Tez. It seems for the most part your SAS client won't even know the difference, and so far I haven't ran into any issues with yarn running Tez. There may be a few smaller projects out there, but these are the only ones I run across.